# Is it possible to modify an iPhone app to make it run full-screen on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have a paid iPhone app, and I'd like to create an updated version that will run as an iPhone app until the user completes an in-app purchase that will have the app use the full screen.

Is there any way to change an app from a small-sized iPhone app to a full-screen iPad app after the app has already been distributed?

Comment: Most apps I've seen like this have a 2X button in the corner that you can push to get them to go full-screen.  Some sort of zoom thing.  It doesn't look great, of course, because you're quadrupling the size of the pixels.

Comment: Why do you want iPad users to pay twice for your app so it will run properly on the iPad? From what you describe, a user with an iPad, that doesn't have your app, will first need to pay for the "iPhone" app and load it on their iPad. Then they would need to use IAP to upgrade the "iPhone" app to work properly on their iPad. That's a bad idea. Either make a separate iPad app so user's can buy the version they want or make a universal app and let users install it on all of their devices after only paying once.

Comment: It would be both - there would be a dedicated iPad app, and the existing iPhone app would have a (discounted) IAP to upgrade it to the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: No, it's not possible.

**Longer Answer**: 
This would involve dynamically setting the build settings (specifically **Targeted Device Family**) at runtime. These settings however, are read and compile/build time. The solution is not impossible, would involve rebuilding the app with different settings. This is unlikely to be permitted by Apple anyway

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is check in your app for any payment made and then if the app has been paid load different data.

The easiest way would be to load different xib files for your layout if the user has paid. The user would however need to quit and relaunch the app to have the payment taken into accound. And you would need in your code to programatically decide to load one xib or the other. But it's doable.